# Split date into intervals

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to make a one to many date relationship, so bucketing my current date range into half-yearly intervals.

Buckets: 0-6months, 6-12months, 12-18months, 18-24months, +24months (taken into account overlap)

Example:

Table

| Name | Start_Date | End_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ | 2020-01-01 | 2022-01-01 |

Desired output

| Name | Start_Date | End_Date | Interval_Start_Date | Interval_End_Date | Date_Bucket |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ | 2020-01-01 | 2022-01-01 | 2020-01-01 (Start_Date) | 2020-06-30 | 0-6months |
| XYZ | 2020-01-01 | 2022-01-01 | 2020-07-01 | 2020-12-31 | 6-12months |
| XYZ | 2020-01-01 | 2022-01-01 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-06-30 | 12-18months |
| XYZ | 2020-01-01 | 2022-01-01 | 2021-07-01 | 2021-12-31 | 18-24months |
| XYZ | 2020-01-01 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 (End_Date) | +24months |

The code I have right now:

```
select
a.name,
a.start_date,
a.end_date
from table a
```

which outputs [Table], with many more rows - only showing one in the example for now.

Comment: How big *could* the range be? Always 2 years, 2 years or less, 20 years?

Comment: @Larnu Some of the ranges could be over 1000 days, so well over 30 months. All of these ranges would get bucketed into the +24months bucket. The majority are anywhere between 0-24 months. 2 years was just an example to cover all the buckets.

Comment: Also, I must admit, your date boundaries feel "wrong". I would expect the second boundary to start on `2020-06-01` and the prior finish on `2020-05-31`. Otherwise your first boundary is 6 months and 1 day, while the rest of 6 months.

Comment: In fact, the first boundary is only 5 months?

Comment: @Larnu Ah my bad, I have edited the table accordingly. It covers the overlaps and miscounts now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives you the expected results, however, your buckets are oddly different lengths. The first bucket, for example, is only 5 months and one day in length, where as the rest are 6 months. I have therefore given an answer to give the expected results, which does **not** reflect the description of putting the results into 6 month buckets. Though you should be able to easily change this if that is your *true* requirement:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable ([Name] varchar(3),
                         StartDate date,
                         EndDate date);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
VALUES ('XYZ','2020-01-01','2022-01-01'),
       ('XYZ','2020-01-01','2021-01-01');
GO
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT YT.Name,
           YT.StartDate,
           YT.EndDate,
           CASE V.IntervalStart WHEN 0 THEN YT.StartDate
                                ELSE DATEADD(DAY,1,DATEADD(MONTH,V.IntervalStart,YT.StartDate))
           END AS IntervalStartDate,
           CASE V.IntervalStart WHEN 0 THEN DATEADD(MONTH,V.IntervalEnd,YT.StartDate)
                                ELSE ISNULL(DATEADD(DAY,1,DATEADD(MONTH,V.IntervalEnd,YT.StartDate)),YT.EndDate)
           END AS IntervalEndDate,
           V.IntervalStart,
           V.IntervalEnd
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT
         CROSS APPLY(VALUES(0,5),(5,11),(11,17),(17,23),(23,NULL))V(IntervalStart,IntervalEnd))
SELECT Name,
       StartDate,
       EndDate,
       IntervalStartDate,
       CASE WHEN IntervalEndDate > EndDate THEN EndDate ELSE IntervalEndDate END AS IntervalEndDate,
       CASE WHEN IntervalEnd IS NULL THEN '+24months' ELSE CONCAT(IntervalStart,'-',IntervalEnd,'months') END AS DateBucket
FROM CTE
WHERE IntervalStartDate < EndDate;
GO


DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=c93b42e647dfeeb8326f61efaeb0313c)

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this, using common table expressions recursion:

```
;with Raw_Data as
(
    select Name, Start_Date, End_Date, 
        Start_Date as IntervalStartDate, 
        DATEADD(M,5,Start_Date) as IntervalEndDate, 
        1 as Interval 
    from YourTable
    union all 
    select Name, Start_Date, End_Date, 
        IntervalEndDate+1 as IntervalStartDate, 
        IIF(Interval=4,End_Date, DATEADD(M,6,IntervalEndDate)) as IntervalEndDate, 
        Interval+1 as Interval 
    from Raw_Data where Interval <= 4
) 
select Name, Start_Date, End_Date, 
        IIF(IntervalStartDate < End_Date, IntervalStartDate, NULL) as IntervalStartDate, 
        IIF(IntervalEndDate < End_Date, IntervalEndDate, End_Date) as IntervalEndDate,
        Interval 
from Raw_Data                                                                                           
where IntervalStartDate < End_Date
order by Name, Interval
```